# JPA oneToMany self mapping

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, mapping, one-to-many

i have a jpa entity mapped as :

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "CATEGORIES")
public class Category {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(name = "ID_CATEGORY")
    private int idCategory;

    @Column(name = "POSITION")
    private int position;

    @Column(name = "SEO_VALUE")
    private String seoValue;

    @Column(name = "VALUE")
    private String value;

    @Column(name = "DESCRIPTION")
    private String description;        

    @Column(name = "SMART_CODE")
    private String smartCode;
```

I need to join Category with himself using the SMART_CODE field .
I tried mapping as :

```
    @OneToMany(mappedBy="smartCategory")
    private List<Category> smartList = new ArrayList<Category>();

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="SMART_CODE", referencedColumnName="SMART_CODE",insertable=false,         updatable=false)
    private Category smartCategory;
```

but it doesn't works .

I have a table Categories that have a field SMART_CODE . 
The SMART_CODE is used to join records inside the table like :

```
    idCategory .. ... ... .. SMART_CODE

    1          .. ... ... .. 2000034
    2          .. ... ... .. 2000034 
    .................................
    100        .. ... ... .. 2000034
```

I want to map my Category Entity to get a list of categories with the same SMART_CODE (smartList) .

Can anyone help me?

Thanks

Carlo

Comment: `but it doesn't works`, can you add more details on what is not working? Any exceptions?

Comment: JPA try to find Category using smart_code as id. I want a query like : smartList = select c from Category c where c.smartCode = ? for every category

Comment: please add what you wanted to do in your post clearly.

Comment: I have a Entity : Category that have a code SMART_CODE (field of db table). The SMART_CODE is commmon for a lot of Category records. I want to map the Category Entity to get a list of category as smartList (the sql query to get all smart categories is select * from category where smart_code = xxxxx )

Comment: I mean to say to add whatever you want by updating your question, so you will get better help in SO. Adding it in comments is difficult to read.

Answer (score 0):

I've spotted something in the line below

```
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="SMART_CODE", referencedColumnName="SMART_CODE",insertable=false,         updatable=false)
    private Category smartCategory;
```

instead change it to the following

```
    @ManyToOne(cascade=CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn(name="SMART_CODE",nullable=true)
    private Category smartCategory;
```